# 403 Forbidden. when serving multipage app via cloudfront from s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In general everything works, I have a gatsby generated static website, s3 bucket setup for static hosting and a cloudfront distribution for serving the files. The problem is when I go to a subpage and refresh the page or go to a url directly I get a 403 error. This does not happen when I append `/index.html` at the end of the url.

In my cloudfront settings I have default root object set to `index.html` so according to the documentation everything should work. This is not a SPA, so setting 403 error page to `index.html` won't help - it will just redirect to home page.

The desired behaviour I'm after is when user goes to url `http://example.com/path/to/directory`, index.html file from `/path/to/directory/index.html` is served.

S3 Bucket permissions:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::[bucket-name]/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/[user]"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::[bucket-name]/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "3",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/[user]"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::[bucket-name]/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Have you defined `Default Root Object` as `index.html` in your CF distro?

Comment: "In my cloudfront settings I have default root object set to index.html"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I stumbled upon the same issue with the gatsby localised pages when using cloudfront with S3.

It works fine when navigating from the root index document. But it doesn't when you try to directly call the subdirectory from the url request.

**Reason**:

Cloudfront `Default Root Object` behaves differently from the `Index Document` of S3. So even if an index file is present in the subdirectory, Cloudfront will not return it on direct url request. You can read more [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/DefaultRootObject.html)

**Solutions**:

1. Use LamdaEdge function for Cloudfront to append `index.html` to url request if it jncludes subdirectory
2. Simply use S3 as a Website Hoster, and add `index.html` as an Index Document. Though, you'll not get the low-latency performance of the Cloudfront.

Comment: You can also add an error behavior in CloudFront to return a 200 with the document `/index.html` whenever it receives a 403 from S3. If you're not happy with overriding 403s globally on your CloudFront distrbution, you can add the `s3:ListObjects`  permission in your bucket policy for CloudFront, that way S3 will return 404s instead of 403s for non-existing objects and you do the configuration of the Error Behavior based on 404 instead of 403

Answer (score 0):

Cloudfront's `Default Root Object` will apply only when a user requests the root URL, not for subfolders.
Index document for subfolders needs to be configured in S3: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/IndexDocumentSupport.html